# Using npm install in a blazor project

Tags: c#, npm, blazor

i am trying to use "npm install vue-metro-tile --save" in the package Manager Console of a Blazor project and got a error i don't know how to fix.

this is a navigation plugin that i'm trying to you in the home page of a website. i'm assuming i need to install a new dependence but i don't know what.

> PM> npm install vue-metro-tile --save
>
> npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + npm install vue-metro-tile --save
>   + ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: How did you install node.js / npm? It doesn't seem to be recognized as a command. Can you use it outside the Package Manager Console? Like in Cmd, Powershell or Git Bash?

Comment: Yes i can in Cmd and it downloaded some folders, but not sure what to do with them

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install Node.Js, so npm will be recognized.

start here : https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need node:
https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

> npm is installed with Node.js

Otherwise, I have found this blog:
Here's [a link](https://medium.com/swlh/using-npm-packages-with-blazor-2b0310279320)!  > Using npm packages with Blazor.

Enjoy.